# Why did Obi-Wan bring Luke with him to Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

The whole plan was to hide the Skywalker twins away until they are ready to face the Sith, and yet Luke has only just been told vaguely about his parents, not even the idea that he is Force-sensitive, let alone begun training in the ways of the Force.

With Leia already in jeopardy in the Empire's hands, it seems even more critical than ever to safeguard a rather helpless Luke. So, what led Obi-Wan to decide that the time has come to bring Luke into the picture even though progress on any training planned for him is still at an absolute zilch?

Does the situation, somehow, led Obi-Wan to think "the time has come for Luke to face to Sith"?

Comment: He was gonna train him. He was gonna "learn the ways of the Force".

Comment: Well, what was Obi-Wan gonna do, just leave Luke on Tatooine alongside his charred Aunt and Uncle?

Answer (score 3):

According to the film's official novelisation, Ben Kenobi recognises that the mission has a non-trivial amount of risk involved. Having twice as many participants (especially a young eager pilot with excellent marksmanship, superior physical prowess and who's strong in the Force) more than doubles their chances of success.

Note the additional dialogue.

> *“I need your help, Luke,” Kenobi explained, his manner a combination
> of sadness and steel. “I’m getting too old for this kind of thing.
> **Can’t trust myself to finish it properly on my own. This mission is
> far too important.”** He nodded toward Artoo Detoo. “You heard and saw
> the message.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

Had Luke **not** come with him, Obi-Wan would have died on the Death Star and although Vader would have probably still engineered Leia's escape on the Falcon, without Luke to fly his X-Wing, the Rebellion's attempts to destroy the Death Star would have been in vain.

---

Ben also thinks that he can see the will of the Force in Luke bringing the droids to him.

> *The old man suppressed a smile, aware that Luke’s destiny had already
> been determined for him. It had been ordained five minutes before he
> had learned about the manner of his father’s death. It had been
> ordered before that when he had heard the complete message. It had
> been fixed in the nature of things when he had first viewed the
> pleading portrait of the beautiful Senator Organa awkwardly projected
> by the little ’droid. Kenobi shrugged inwardly. Likely it had been
> finalized even before the boy was born. Not that Ben believed in
> predestination, but he did believe in heredity—and in the force.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: On top of all the good stuff in this answer, there's also the fact that *Luke* brought R2D2 to *Ben.*  Which means Ben knew it would only be a matter of time before Vader found Luke in the course of chasing the stolen plans, and thus his "hiding place" on Tatooine was no longer safe anyway.  As we see in the film, when the Empire destroys the moisture farm.  He has to keep Luke close at least until he can find another safe place to hide him, and if he proves himself ready for bigger things along the way, so be it.